# Making a TypeScript Declaration for Existing JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

A former colleague wrote a small chunk of JavaScript (I'm not even sure what to call it.  Class?  Library?) which I'm now trying to use in a TypeScript portion of our application.  We've had some similar situations where we merely added some kind of declaration to a d.ts file.  I'm trying to do that now, but I'm getting hung up on the fact that the object I want to use is also a function in the original JS.  That is, it is created via the `new` operator, yet the constructed object has methods.  I'm hoping someone can tell me the best approach for this.

Here is the original JavaScript class/library:

```
(function (geographies, $) {
    geographies.map = function(elementId) {
        var self = this;
        // Other members elided

        // Public Functions
        self.findAddress = function (addressDesc, callback){
            // elided
        }

        // Other public methods elided


        // Private Methods
        function _example() {
            // elided
        }

        // Other private methods elided
    }
}(window.geographies = window.geographies || {}, jQuery));
```

Of course, this results in `geographies` being created in the global window namespace, and `geographies` has a member, `map` which has methods, but is created via `new` with a string parameter passed in.  Here's an example of `geographies.map` being used in existing code (in this context, `self` merely refers to a containing component):

```
if ((self.editAddress.cityId() && self.editAddress.addressLine1())) {
    if (map === null) {
        map = new geographies.map("addressMapDiv");
    }
    self.mapVisible(true);
    var query = (self.editAddress.addressLine1() ? self.editAddress.addressLine1() : "") +
        (self.editAddress.cityDescription() ? " " + self.editAddress.cityDescription() : "") +
        (self.editAddress.zipCode() ? " " + self.editAddress.zipCode() : "");
    console.log(query);
    map.findAddress(query);
}
```

Now we're starting to use `geographies` in TypeScript and thus want some way to get Intellisense and type-checking on it, but there is no plan to reimplement it.  We merely want TypeScript to give us a way to use what will be the same object in the window namespace that already exists.  I've taken a few cracks at it, but none have seemed to quite make sense.  I think the biggest problem is that `geographies.map` needs to be newable and accept the string parameter `elementId` , while also becoming an object with methods of its own.  Here is my latest failed attempt:

```
interface Map {
    constructor(elementId: string): Map;
    findAddress(addressDesc: any, callback: any): any;
    // Other signatures elided
}

interface GeographiesStatic {
    map: Map;
    // Other members elided
}

declare var geographies: GeographiesStatic;
```

Should I be using `declare class`?  Interfaces?  Do I need the `declare var` at the bottom, or will that somehow kill the object of the same name that's already in the window namespace?  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code uses the revealing module pattern, which is usually represented with `namespace` in TypeScript. An easy declaration for this file would be:

```
declare namespace geographies {
  class map {
    constructor(name: string);
    findAddress(desc: any, cb: any): any;
  }
}
```